# Lubuntu giving black screen after install on laptop with NVIDIA GPU, unable to modify grub

Tags: boot, grub2, nvidia, lubuntu, nomodeset

Trying to install Lubuntu on a brand new MSI gaming laptop because it's much more lightweight and snappy than Windows. However, I noticed that if I start the Lubuntu LiveCD without adding `nomodeset`, it results in a black screen. So I had to install by selecting the Safe Graphics option.

Now that Lubuntu is installed, I tried to go into `/etc/default/grub` and add `nomodeset`, but when running `sudo update-grub`, it says it can't find `/cow`.

So then I tried mounting the `/dev/nvme0n1p2` drive to `/mnt` and chrooting it to directly edit grub, but then when running `update-grub` it throws up an error and says `cannot find a device for / (is /dev mounted?)`

I'm at a loss, I don't know what to do. And I've completely reinstalled Lubuntu twice now, I'm worried about wearing out my NVMe drive.

Comment: Providing release details is always helpful; and if you're installing with a LTS release; which media you use as that controls which kernel stack is used by default (*we currently have no idea as you've provided few specifics*), nor if you tried loading any proprietary drivers as per the [manual](https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/4/4.3/software_sources.html)  Note: as I don't know your release; I've just used 21.10 manual link being the latest *stable* release of Lubuntu

Comment: In a *brand new MSI gaming laptop* there's absolutely NO REASON to opt for a lightweight flavor. You can use standard Ubuntu and you won't notice any difference, absolutely nothing!